# Issue with newline when passing text from javascript to php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, newline

I need to pass a bunch of text from javascript to php using ajax and save it to database. I can only use javascript, not jquery. This text need to include newline and characters like this `{}!@#$%^&*/?(){}`.

The value I passed is in associative array `{ id:[], text:[] }`
 So I use `encodeURIComponent()` for the text[], and then `JSON.stringify()` it.
From the PHP side, I use `urldecode()` and `json_decode()`, to decode the text.

This is how I do the ajax call with javascript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { //blah blah }
xhr.send(params);
```

Now, the problem occur, whenever there is newline in the text. json_decode() will churn out NULL if there's newline. Why is that?

This is the solution I come up with. I notice `encodeURIComponent()` will change newline to `%0A`. So if I use regex to convert every `%0A` to `\n`. The problem is solved. But again, why? Why `urldecode()` on PHP side couldn't convert the newline properly?

Comment: add the php code as well

Comment: I couldn't edit the original post. So this is how I get the text from PHP side:
$postValue=$_POST["text"];
$postValue=urldecode($postValue);
$notesToSave = json_decode($postValue, true);
//here, $notesToSave will have NULL value

Comment: where did you get the 'notes' key? As far as I can see in your post you have only 'id' and 'text'

Comment: Sorry, copy paste the wrong thing. Fix it. Anyway, I can get the value to PHP side no problem. The value only turn NULL when newline is involved.

Comment: could you pls show the var_dump($postValue) in that case?

Comment: This is var_dump($postValue) before json_encode():
string(45) "{"id":[436],"notes":["random
random
random"]}"

After json_encode, it just shows NULL. It's not very clear, but there is newline after every word 'random' in the array.

Comment: are you able to make json_decode first and only then urldecode of your string?

Comment: Yes, the value is NULL after json_decode() even if I never run urldecode().

Comment: maybe that could help you:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#112084

Comment: Ok, seems like there are some issues with json_decode(). I will browse through the comments in the link. Thanks.